# Both If - Else is true

Tags: javascript

Edited ( HTML CODE )
I got problem with my if - else statement (my code is not complete yet)

Edited v2:

Sorry i'm so busy today, so i will make clear of my question : I have 3 If statement , "1st and 3rd if" run when something was typed in the box ,
"2nd if" run when text in the box being removed ,

and because we already have "if statement" for blank box (2nd if) so that means we have 2 case might happen : user typed something similar to "countries" array
Ex : A for Albania, V for Vietnam etc...
and another case is user typed something different from any country in "countries" array Ex: Z (no country begin with Z)

SO the problem is why 2 case happen at the same time ( 1st if and 3rd if )

and about the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" can i fix it ???

This is my HTML Code

```html
<div class="test">
    <form id="myInput">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
    </form>
    <button style="padding-top:100px;" id="DCM">abc</button>
    </div>
```

```js
var countries = ["Albania","VietNam","Thai","Han","Lao"];

countries.map(function(x){ return x.toUpperCase() })

var searchinput = document.querySelector('#myInput input');

searchinput.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){

var searchChar = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
var parent = e.target.parentNode;
var c = document.createElement("div");
var a = document.createElement("div");
a.setAttribute("id", "autocomplete-list");
a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
c.appendChild(a);
parent.appendChild(c);

for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    if (countries[i].substr(0,searchChar.length).toUpperCase() == searchChar ) {
        var b = document.createElement("div");
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + countries[i].substr(0, searchChar.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += countries[i].substr(searchChar.length);
        a.appendChild(b);   
    }
    if(searchChar.length == 0)  {
        var y = document.getElementById("autocomplete-list");
        y.parentNode.remove();
    }
    else{
        console.log("He");
    }
}
```

This code is about autocomplete , and when i type nothing in the search bar, it will run the "2nd if" , it worked but return error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null"

And 1 more question is in my code , if i type something it run "1st if" or the "3rd if" because in "1st if" it have condition, and "3rd if" is else, but when i type something , it's all run together exept "2nd if"

Sorry for my bad English , i'm not good at writing

Comment: please share the html code

Comment: The second if (with the else) is now completely separate from the first if. You should write `else if`, so `if (condition1){ block1; } else if (condition 2) { block2; } else { block3; }`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want only *one* of the three `if`s to happen, you should do `if (condition1) { ... } else if (condition2) { ... } else { ... }`. You're getting `Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null"` because your code is not finding an element with an ID of `autocomplete-list`. Without seeing the HTML, we cannot tell you why this is the case.

Comment: i added my html code , sorry i forhot

Comment: please add an answer to your question

Comment: i added my question , i'm really sorry for any confuse with my English .

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If you want only one of the three ifs to happen, you should do `if (condition1) { ... } else if (condition2) { ... } else { ... }.` You're getting Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" because your code is not finding an element with an ID of autocomplete-list. Without seeing the HTML, we cannot tell you why this is the case. [Tyler Roper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026606/tyler-roper)

Comment: i added my question , i'm really sorry for any confuse with my English

Comment: i understand the "if -else " issue but do you have any idea to fix the 'parentNode' ? any better way ?

Comment: Hello, can you help me 1 more question ?? i edited if-else statement with else if but it wont run the "2nd if", i used console.log(searchChar.length) to check if the value is '0' , its true but the second if wont run unless i remove the "else"